# How can I lower the actuation force of a key switch?

Tags: keyboard

One common criteria when choosing a keyboard is the actuation force of its key switches. Is it possible to lower the actuation force of a key switch?

E.g., to reduce the total key travel distance, one can add o-rings.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, yes. However, it greatly depends on the specific switch's construction. Which switch are you planing on using? Adding an O-ring may not change where in the stroke the switch is actuated, and may actually increase actuation force.

Keep in mind, that whatever change you may want, you'd have to do it for all of the keys that you'd like, not just one. It would probably be easier and more reliable to replace desired switches with compatible switches of lower actuation force rather than modding them.

Comment: The Cherry switches are going to be quite difficult to successfully modify to your liking. They do have o-rings, but they don't alter actuation; they only stop the "clack" of the key cap hitting the switch at the end of the stroke, after the switch has already been picked up as "actuated". I'd suggest grabbing a "switch tester" that has 6-8 switches, so you can see how each one feels.